# google drive does not allow signed apk file download

Tags: android-studio, google-drive-api, apk

I am generating a "Signed Bundle/APK" file using Android Studio Chipmunk version. I upload the output-metadata.json and app-release.apk file to google drive. When I try to download this .apk file from my computer, it is "Virus detected. Download anyway" and in the phone it is not allowing me download at all. In the phone it is throwing a "Download error" as notification.

It has been working fine till couple of months back with the same building and delivering over google drive. I am signing the .apk file and the apksigner and jar signer shows the .apk file as signed.

In phone settings, I have also allowed installed from downloaded apk files.

I tried building the apk file from linux and osx and receiving the same error. How to fix this problem?

Comment: I would start uploading your APK to https://virustotal.com. If it is really a false-positive it has a good chance that it is white-listed by the different anti-virus engines (uploaded binaries are shared with all the AV companies).

Comment: I uploaded the apk to virustotal.com and google detects Trojan.androidos.banker.  All the other vendors didnt report anything. What is this error? How to request Google to unflag this? What is wrong with generation process that made Google flag my apk like this?

Comment: Do you have any Update? I am currently encountering the same problem. The previous versions worked without problems. As of today, I can no longer install this ones either

Comment: We are able to transfer apk files using other services such as dropbox/onedrive etc.